# Telethon respond to a message using the message id

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

I want to respond to a message in a Telegram channel, using the message id, from the message to respond to, with python.

Example:

```
await client.msg_respond(entity=entity, msg_id=msg_id, msg="Hello")
```

Is there something like that?

Answer (score 4):

It works like this:

```
await client.send_message(entity=entity,message="reply msg", reply_to=msgID)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can mark your own answer as accepted if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is usual example show you how to do this:

```
@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=-1001672571848))
async def my_event_handler(event):
    msg = event.message

    await client.send_message(entity=-1001672571848,
                reply_to=msg.id, message=text
            )
```